# How to turn off Two-Step verification

Tags: icloud, apple-id, two-step-authentication, two-factor-authentication

How I can turn off the Two-Step verification, it's driving me crazy. 
here is ICLOUD security settings from my MacBook Pro-2015

As you can see from the below pictures I don't have the option to turn off the two-Factor authentication.

[image]

Another screenshot of my ICLOUD's security [apple.com](https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a Turn off link as shown below:

[image]